# Is an API RESTful if it only uses GET/Retrieve

Tags: rest

If an API only allows retrieval of data (through GET) and does not allow Create, Update or Delete is it still RESTful?

I question this because Wikipedia says "When a client holds a representation of a resource, including any metadata attached, it has enough information to modify or delete the resource." as a constraint of REST.

I'm sorry if this seems like a silly question but I'm trying to get to the point where I can say 'I understand REST' confidently.

Comment: The state being sent to the client from a GET request may indeed contain all of the information required to update that state at a later time.  The server doesn't need to *permit* that update or expose the functionality for it, but the client can still hold the information necessary to change state.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a system can use REST even if it doesn't allow modification of the resources.

The most common implementation and use of REST is HTTP 1.1 used for the world wide web (even if the RESTfulness is implemented vith varying success). A vast majority of the resources are read-only.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the API is still RESTful if even if it does not implement all of the verbs.  This simply will not make sense for all resources.  Some verbs may not apply, or a client may not be authorized to perform them.

Take for example newspaper articles.  I could see that GET is the only available verb as the news site may only publish the API for reading (i.e. getting) the articles.

As for the Wikipedia definition, I would change that slightly to say "it has enough information to *attempt to* modify or delete the resource."

And the API can communicate support/non-support of certain verbs by response codes.  If DELETE is not supported, a client DELETE request would see a HTTP 405 (not supported) response.

Answer (score 1):

REST is not coupled to any particular protocol, so what methods are being used does not affect the RESTfulness of an API, as long as the methods are used for their standardized behavior and any deviations are documented. For instance, there's nothing preventing you from having a similar "read-only" API implemented over FTP, using the RETR method.

What really matters is how clients obtain the URIs for the resources they are retrieving. If they are using out of band information, like URI patterns in documentation, it's not RESTFUL. Resources should have links referencing each other and clients should be able to find anything they want starting from an initial entry point URI. Do some googling for HATEOAS if you have doubts on that.